# Como puedo descargar una pagina web con contenido dinámico usando python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Buenas necesito descargar una pagina web, lo hice con requests pero el contenido descargado no es igual al que se ve en el navegador, creo que es porque el contenido cambia mediante javascript una vez en el navegador.

Mi codigo:

```py
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.mipagina.com/")

file = open("archivo2.html", "w")
file.write(r.text)
file.close()
```

Respuesta

```html
<div>
 <ul class="contenido-dinamico"></ul>
</div>
```

donde el contenido que necesito esta dentro de `<ul></ul>`

Comment: La vía típica (no muy sencilla, pero es lo que hay) es usar Selenium. Mira [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/297176/7123) por ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias entendi que lo que tengo que hacer es renderizarlo, ya sea con selenium o dryscrape u otro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré una solución usando https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/

Les comparto la solución.

Primero instale `requests-html`, esto solo me funciono con python3.7

```sh
pip install requests-html
```

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get("mipaginaweb.com")
r.html.render()  # Esta linea ejecuta el javascript que cambia valores del dom de la pagina

# guardo el html con contenido dinamico
file = open("miarchivo.html", "w")
file.write(r.html.html)
file.close()
```

Respuesta.-

```html
<div>
 <ul class="contenido-dinamico">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  ...
 </ul>
</div>
```

Espero pueda servir a mas de uno.